# Monodroid bitmap to stream

Tags: stream, bitmap, xamarin.android

does any one know how to turn a bitmap into a stream on monodroid? I'm creating a bitmap from a url stream then resizing that bitmap so I can store it on a file for later use.

thank you

Answer (score 2):

If you're talking about [Android.Graphics.Bitmap](http://docs.mono-android.net/index.aspx?link=T%3aAndroid.Graphics.Bitmap), you could use [Bitmap.Compress(CompressFormat, Stream)](http://docs.mono-android.net/index.aspx?link=M%3aAndroid.Graphics.Bitmap.Compress(Android.Graphics.Bitmap.CompressFormat%2cSystem.Int32%2cSystem.IO.Stream)) to write the `Bitmap` contents to a [Stream](http://docs.mono-android.net/index.aspx?link=T%3aSystem.IO.Stream).

Answer (score 1):

This is what [JonP](https://stackoverflow.com/users/83444/jonp) was referring to. Of course you can select whatever format you'd like.

```
using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    if (bmp.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Jpeg, 80, stream))
    {
        //do whatever needed with stream
    }
}
```